# EREQUEST Incorrect syntax near 'END'

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions

I created a simple SQL Server function. Once I added the `IF Else` block, it started showing the error:

> EREQUEST Incorrect syntax near 'END'

Though the code seems straight forward and looked into several forum posts as well, I am not able to figure out where the issue is exactly. Please help.

```
CREATE FUNCTION Detect_Subscription(@ID INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
BEGIN
DECLARE @Status INT, @customer VARCHAR(20);
SELECT @Status = COUNT(*) FROM premium WHERE premium.user_id = @ID;
IF @Status > 0 THEN SET @customer = 'Premium';
ELSE SET @customer = 'Free';    
END IF;
RETURN @customer;   
END
```

Comment: Are you sure, you have write your function for MySql? It seems Sql Server

Comment: Thanks for the help Joe! :)  Yes you are right, I got them mixed up. *facepalm moment*

Comment: There's no `END IF` in T-SQL. It's either `IF {boolean statement} {true statement} ELSE {False Statement}` or `IF {boolean statement} BEGIN {True statements} END ELSE BEGIN {False statements} END`

Comment: Learn good habits. There is no reason to actually COUNT rows to test existence - and it is less efficient to do so.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @SMor Noted! Still on the learning phase :)

Answer (score 1):

Your function seems right for SQL Server.

You can simplify your function as follow:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Detect_Subscription(@ID INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @customer VARCHAR(20);

    SELECT
        @Customer =
        CASE
            WHEN COUNT(1) > 0 THEN 'Premium'
            ELSE 'Free'
        END
    FROM premium WHERE premium.user_id = @ID;

    RETURN @customer;   
END
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the use of `IF` is fine.  I would just pair it with `EXISTS`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Detect_Subscription (
    @ID INT
) RETURNS VARCHAR(20) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @customer VARCHAR(20);

    IF (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM premium p WHERE p.user_id = @ID))
    BEGIN
        SET @customer = 'Premium';
    END;
    ELSE SET @customer = 'Free';    

    RETURN @customer;   
END;
```

This is marginally faster than `COUNT(*)` if you can have multiple rows in `premium` for a given user (and nano-marginally faster if that is not possible).

Important points:

- SQL Server does not have `END IF`.
- SQL Server requires `AS` when defining a function.